# Calling function in main which separates a string using strtok (trouble with pointers)

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I am writing a program in C where user inputs a string (phone contact information) with no spaces but info such as last name, first name, etc are separated by commas.

What I am trying to do is write a function where the string field between commas becomes a token (using `strtok_r` function) and is assigned to a string array and print each token at the end of the program.

The code below is my attempt so far but it does not print what I expect. The result is random ASCII characters which I'm guessing is because of how bad I am with pointers. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void commaCut(char *input, char *command, char *last, char *first, char *nick, char *detail, char *phone);

int main()
{
char *str, *token, *command;
char *last, *first, *nick, *detail, *phone, *saveptr;

char input[100];
int commaCount = 0;
int j;
str = fgets(input,100,stdin);
commaCut(str, command, last, first, nick, detail, phone);
printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",command,last,first,nick,detail,phone);
exit(0);
}

void commaCut(char *input, char *command, char *last, char *first, char *nick, char *detail, char *phone)
{
  char *token, *saveptr;
  int j;
  int commaCount = 0;
  for (j = 0; ; j++, commaCount++, input = NULL)
  {
    token = strtok_r(input, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
      break;
    if (commaCount == 0)
      command = token;
    if (commaCount == 1)
      last = token;
    if (commaCount == 2)
      first = token;
    if (commaCount == 3)
      nick = token;
    if (commaCount == 4)
      detail = token;
    if (commaCount == 5)
      phone = token;
 }
```

Comment: I said it'd be easir, not that this is c++.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pointers `first` etc. that are modified in the `commaCut` function are *copies* of the pointers in `main`, so the pointers in `main` remain unchanged and uninitialised, and point to arbitrary memory locations. You need to pass the address of these pointers to change the values of the `main` pointers.

Change the function to

```
void commaCut(char *input, char **command, char **last, char **first, char **nick, char **detail, char **phone)
{
  char *token, *saveptr;
  int j;
  int commaCount = 0;
  for (j = 0; ; j++, commaCount++, input = NULL)
  {
    token = strtok_r(input, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
      break;
    if (commaCount == 0)
      *command = token;
    if (commaCount == 1)
      *last = token;
    if (commaCount == 2)
      *first = token;
    if (commaCount == 3)
      *nick = token;
    if (commaCount == 4)
      *detail = token;
    if (commaCount == 5)
      *phone = token;
 }
```

and call it

```
commaCut(str, &command, &last, &first, &nick, &detail, &phone);
```

in `main`.